# camera pose estimation using solvePnP, c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to estimate camera pose using solvePnP i have two problems: How can I convert focal length from mm to pixel unit? Can anyone give me some ground truth to check my code? I need four coplanar points for this and intrinsic camera parameters and the result.

Answer (score 1):

Converting focal length in mm to pixels is just dividing by the size of a pixel in mm

The coplanar points comes from you knowing the design of the object you are looking at.

The best way of getting the intrinsic matrix is to use the opencv calibration functions http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html